# Formatting using Row & Column coordinates in GSpread python

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I couldn't find any resources on how to format the google spreadsheet in gspread python using the row and column values instead of A1 notations.

I have a spreadsheet with 50 rows and I don't want to find the notation of the 50th column. Rather I like to use the row and column coordinates like **(1,50) -> first row with 50 columns** to make them **bold** and adjusting the **width** of all the columns.

Please suggest and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to format the cells using row and column coordinates using the below function. Accumulated different answers available for the related questions in Stackoverflow. Thank you.

```
def formatHeaderRow(gs, ws):

    #to change the column width of the specific range of cells using row and column numbers
    sheetId = ws._properties['sheetId']
    numOfColumns = 26 # Keep your column number here
    body = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "updateDimensionProperties": {
                    "range": {
                        "sheetId": sheetId,
                        "dimension": "COLUMNS",
                        "startIndex": 0, #from A1
                        "endIndex": numOfColumns # 26 -> A26
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "pixelSize": "150"
                    },
                    "fields": "pixelSize"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    res = gs.batch_update(body)
    
    #to bold the first row using row number
    ws.format("1", {
        "textFormat": {
            "bold": True
            }
    })
```